# "Working Plan" in PhD application

Tags: phd, application, research-proposal

I am currently writing my "research proposal" for my PhD in Statistics application, basically I am asked to provide:

- Project description (activities, methodologies, expected results).
- State of the Art.
- Objectives.
- References.
- *Working program.*

I am not sure what a "working program" really is given that in practice I've described every aspect regarding my future research in the previous items.
I've contacted the PhD office but I didn't received an answer, I've contacted my advisor and he was as clueless as myself.

Hope you guys could shed some light over this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who will finally read this plan? Expert in your field, final scrutinizer of your thesis?

Comment: Actually it will be read by the admission committee. It's not an actual research proposal but just part of the admission  process.

Comment: Working program then should be working packages or points, how you split up your research in sequential and parallel packages of units of 3 months over 3-6 years on 10-20 pages

Comment: I think that this would be something of a project plan; aims and milestones to achieve by a certain point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The work plan breaks down your project into operational steps, detailing when you will take on which task and for how long. A good work plan is feasible and complete. It signals to the committee that you are realistic and aware of the scope and practicalities of your project. It could look something like this:

[image]

[Source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/PhD-work-plan_fig1_221158846)